# Is There a Way to Disable the USB Device Disconnect/Reconnect Sound for a Specific Device in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, usb

I realize it's possible to disable all USB disconnect/reconnect sounds, but there's some specific devices I want to disable it for, while keeping the sound for the rest. I'm using a USB kvm switch, and the constant booping when I switch it back and forth is grating.

Comment: There is a great long list of individual sounds in Control  Panel, Sounds, Sound tab.  Take a look in there and see if the sound you wish to mute is in there.

Comment: @John by doing that the connect/disconnect sound for all USB drives will be removed.

Comment: If the sound is individually identified, it may work for the one sound. Otherwise what was requested cannot be done.